# Chevy Bolt - High Initial Energy Consumption

Tags: chevrolet, electric-vehicle

We just got a 2023 Bolt and its reporting energy consumption numbers that seem way out of line -- a "lifetime" (all of 152 miles) efficiency of 1.8 mi/kWh, and a "since full charge" (which seems to actually mean "since last charge to charge limit") of 3.2 mi/kWh (over 26 miles).

Those 26 miles were over a route similar to my commute route (in a Kia Niro EV), but with less highway driving. Over the last six months the Niro has averaged 4.2 mi/kWh and on my commute today its energy consumption today was 4.3 mi/kWh. Temperatures here were around 50°F in the morning and high 60s in the afternoon. I would have expected the Bolt to have had similar or even better energy consumption than the Niro since it is lighter with less frontal area and was driving at slower speeds.

Is there some reason to expect the initial energy consumption stats to be low? Or, are these numbers suggesting a potential problem?

Comment: Could it be the vehicle is not broken in yet? This could mean battery efficiency, motor, bearings, tires, etc. While not the same as an ICE powered vehicle, I'd assume you shouldn't expect the "best" <cough> fuel economy straight out the gate. You might want to give it a few laps around the town before you start making comparisons.

Comment: Did you try asking mi/kwh in Bolt forums?

Comment: No. I'm new to the Bolt forums and still figuring out which are the good ones and how to check for questions that are already answered.

Comment: I'm not sure if "breaking in" is what's going on, but the reported efficiency is improving rather dramatically -- with 200 some miles on it now the "lifetime" mi/kWh has more than doubled to 3.9.

Comment: Just noticed that there is a significant discrepancy between the lifetime mi/kWh reported in the vehicle and on the My Chevrolet app. Interesting...